# react-native-expo-cli - Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

[stderr]
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

[stderr]
1: Task failed with an exception.

### [stderr]

[stderr]

- Where:

[stderr]
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradle' line: 21

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.

[stderr]

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

## [stderr]

[stderr]
2: Task failed with an exception.

### [stderr]

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

[stderr]

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

## [stderr]

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

[stderr]
BUILD FAILED in 2m 42s

5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Fail build

1s

Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

i try expo build:android for upload expo project on expo app